# Guard for only one component under named view router - Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, vue-router

I have a named view route:

```
let routes = [
    {
        name: "home",
        path: '/',
        components: {
            default: Home,
            project: ProjectIndex
        }
    }
]
```

I want to protect the "project" route based on user roles but the default Home needs to be accessible for anyone.

I am adding this to the ProjectIndex component:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {

    var user = Spark.state.user;

    if(user.current_role == 'admin' || user.current_role == 'owner'){
        next();
    }

}
```

But the router is executing this code on the Home component also, therefore Home is also affected by this.

I don't think something this simple should be so hard in Vue js.

If I `console.log(to)` I get the route but nothing that tells me which Component will be rendered. I'm hitting a wall here. Please help.

Comment: For any one looking for this, the answer is these are "nested" named views, therefore the route is treated as the same, v-if will condition rendering so my solution was to use created() hook along with v-if, you can even redirect to another route with $router.push.

Answer (score 2):

> I am going to show you how to do it supporting lazy loading too.

```
//this function will do the check and import the component supporting lazy loading
//if the check does not fulfilled then the component will not imported 
function check_condition(name_component) {
    if (name_component === 'Project') { 
      const user = store.state.user

      if (user.current_role == 'admin' || user.current_role == 'owner') {
        return () => import(`@/components/${name_component}.vue`)
      }
      return
    }
    return () => import(`@/components/${name_component}.vue`)
}

export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            components: {
                default: check_condition('Home'),
                project: check_condition('Project')
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            name: 'about',
            component: check_condition('About')
        }
    ]
})
```

I like the above approach.Though of course there are also other ways.
If you don't like the above or it does not fit with your problem you can try the below approach.

Say you have is vuex store state:

```
state: { user: 'admin' //or visitor }
```

And you want to show the `settings_button` component when the user is `admin` but not when is `visitor`:

```
computed: {
  should_show_settings_button () {
    return this.$store.state.user === 'admin'
  }
}

<template v-if="should_show_settings_button">
  <router-view name="settings_button"></router-view>
</template>
```

Comment: Nice approach :).

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: @DiegoPonciano i added another approach to my answer you can take a look to it.Maybe it fits better to your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check `to` url:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  if(to.pathname !== '/') {
      //yours check
  }
  else {
       next();
  }
}
```

Or more complex way is to everytime check array of your routes. You can check by a component name then.

```
let routesObjects = routes.reduce((obj, route) => { obj[route.path] = route.name; return obj; }, {});

beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    let path = to.pathname;
    if(routesObjects.hasOwnProperty(to) && routesObjects[to] !== 'home') {
        //yours check
    }
    else {
         next();
    }
}
```

In case if u have 2 components with the same `pathnam` u could combine a `beforeEach` hook and `meta`

Setup `meta` tag in your component

```
routes: [
    { name: 'home', path: '/', meta: { isHome: true } }
]
```

Then just check it

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.meta.isHome !== undefined && to.meta.isHome) { next(); }
  else { //your check  }
})
```

Comment: The route and path is the same the component different.

Comment: @DiegoPonciano Then you should use another hook. You can't access component instance inside `beforeRouteEnter`

Comment: That is my dilemma what hook to use?

Comment: Should I use created() or mounted()? Don't feel is so clean :/

Comment: @DiegoPonciano how about `beforeEach` and combine it with `meta`?

Comment: Feeling this should be addressed by the framework in a simple native fashion.

Comment: @DiegoPonciano i could update my answer with right solution if u want to

Comment: @DiegoPonciano updated my answer with the right solution

Comment: Meta is for the entire route, please note I am using named views https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views so even the updated solution does not apply.

Comment: I noted the actual name is "nested" named views so now it makes more sense.

Comment: Ok I will use created() hook since now makes sense. (and v-if)